# Python Second for loop only looped once

Tags: python

just wondering why the second loop only loops through once.
I want it so that each item in the stack prints each item in the path.

```
for i in stack:
    print(i)
for j in path:
    print(j)
```

but the second loop is only entered once.

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your question to reflect your actual code

Comment: What is `path`? If `path` is a generator it will be exhausted after the first outer loop.

Comment: Can you give some more info about `path` and are you considering inner loops

Comment: is path a sub-list of stack? If it is, you need to add an extra indent to the loop for j.